# populate csv into database

Tags: php, csv

i have managed to code this CSV file and it is working well..the only problem i am getting is the variable error on the form..i get this error ...Notice: Undefined variable: data in C:\xampp\htdocs\helper.php(527) : runtime-created function on line 22

1. how do i resolve the error? this

   this my sample code...

   ```
   <form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST" action="" >
   CSV<input type="file" name="file" />
   <input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit"/>
   </form>

   //connect to the database
   $connect = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
   mysql_select_db("test",$connect); //select the table
   if(isset($_POST['submit']))
   {

   //get the csv file
   $file = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
   $handle = fopen($file,"r");

    //loop through the csv file and insert into database
   do {
   if ($data[0]) {
       mysql_query("INSERT INTO f38uj_zhgooglemaps_markers (title, addresstext,  published, baloon, icontype, mapid) VALUES
           (
              '".addslashes($data[0])."',
              '".addslashes($data[1])."',
              '".addslashes($data[2])."',
              '".addslashes($data[3])."',
              '".addslashes($data[4])."',
              '".addslashes($data[5])."'
            )
         ");
        }
      } while ($data = fgetcsv($handle,1000,",","'"));

     }

     ?>
   ```

Comment: i noticed but still i just getting error

Comment: It is possible to import data directly using db server.

Comment: my problem is my company needs to import from a remote location so i need to create the markers...i am working on a map

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are three issues here:

1) You're using double quotes, which tells PHP to substitute the value of the variable it finds for what you set it to earlier, see example below.

2) $data isn't defined until the end of the loop, so use a regular while loop and not do-while

3) Your sql query is wrong anyway. You're going to have something to the effect of

```
$data='value',$data='value',$data='value2',$data='value3',$data='value4',



mysql_query("INSERT INTO f38uj_zhgooglemaps_markers (title, addresstext,  published, baloon, icontype, mapid) VALUES
        (
          $data=  '".addslashes($data[0])."',
          $data= '".addslashes($data[1])."',
          $data= '".addslashes($data[2])."',
          $data='".addslashes($data[3])."',
          $data= '".addslashes($data[4])."',
          $data= '".addslashes($data[5])."'
         )
      ");
     }
```

Since you're using do-while, upon the first iteration of the loop, $data will have no value and so PHP throws a runtime warning, since for all the interpreter knows it'll set be set later (which it is in your case). Basically in a do-while the condition isn't checked until after the body runs, so $data = fgetcsv() isn't called until after that first pass through.

You can easily switch this around and make your warning go away, just change this construct:

```
do{
//...
}
while($data=fgetcsv())
```

to this:

```
while($data=fgetcsv()){
//...
}
```

Comment: thanks for the support i tried the while thing on my previous post but it repeats data on the table 3 times..i have modified this now the data dont repeate but on the form i get ..Notice: Undefined variable: data

Comment: When you say "This is my $data", php will find the variable named $data and put its value into the string. However, on the first iteration of your loop, $data is not set. You're using a do-while loop, so the condition isn't checked until after the first iteration, which also means that $data is not being set til after the first iteration. You're trying to substitute a value that doesn't exist yet.

Comment: instead of a do-while loop, just use a while loop. I'll update my answer

Comment: i have used while eg //loop through the csv file and insert into database

while ($data = fgetcsv($handle,1000,",","'"));
    
        if($data=$data[0]) {
            mysql_query("INSERT INTO contacts (contact_first, contact_last, contact_email) VALUES
                (
                    '".addslashes($data[0])."',
                    '".addslashes($data[1])."',
                    '".addslashes($data[2])."'
                )
            ");
        }
    
    
}

?>


and has worked but on the table has repeated with lettes http://www.dmtinc.cl/imagenes/VzJwf.jpg

Comment: @ Zarazthuztra- i understand..i just need help from you experts coz i believe in stack and everybody..i always know here there are gurus and pro

Answer (score 0):

```
$data=$data[0]
```

should be

```
$data==$data[0]
```

You are comparing, not assigning. Especially not in a if-statement

Comment: i have removed..$data=

Answer (score 0):

If this is all of your code, I do not see where you are setting the variable `$data` anywhere, and then you go ahead and do a test on it:

```
if ($data[0]) { ... }
```

You should use the [isset](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) function before making these types of tests, unless you are 100% sure that the variable is not null:

```
if (isset($var)){ ... }
```

and then

```
if ($var) { ... }
```

Comment: He should use a regular while loop anyway, then using fgetcsv will guarantee that the code will not run if the variable is null.

Comment: He sets $data in the do while loop

Comment: @Farkie except that it's a do-while loop. $data isn't set until the body of the loop has already run a single time.

Comment: @Farkie-i  have used regular while-loop and yes its works fine but on the table repeats records 6 times..i needed something to end repition of the record that's why i tried this